# How to remove the least-value duplicate?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which consisting of the following columns:

```
  id      name    value
serial    text    text
```

And I need to remove a row with the least `id` value and `name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL'`. How can I do that in the most optimal way? I tried:

```
DELETE FROM propertie 
WHERE name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL' 
HAVING id = MIN(id) 
GROUP BY name ;
```

and

```
DELETE FROM propertie 
WHERE name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL' 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING id = MIN(id)  ;
```

But it didn't work. Of course,  I can write

```
DELETE FROM propertie 
WHERE id = (SELECT id 
        FROM propertie 
        WHERE name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL' and id = (SELECT MIN(id) 
                            FROM propertie 
                            WHERE name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL')
)
```

but it seems quite wierd to me.

Comment: Is id unique? (E.g. the one and only primary key column.)

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close there, but can simplify your effort with:

```
DELETE FROM propertie 
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) 
            FROM   propertie 
            WHERE  name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL')
```

You could also:

```
DELETE FROM propertie 
WHERE id = (SELECT id
            FROM   propertie 
            WHERE  name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL'
            ORDER BY id
            LIMIT  1)
```

I'm not sure if this is legal PostgreSQL syntax:

```
DELETE FROM   propertie 
WHERE  name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: Well, you could do it with not exists, but I don't think that it would be very efficient at finding that row.

Answer (score 1):

For using the aggregate functions in the delete query, we need to make use of the subqueries as below. I feel this is the optimized way:

```
DELETE FROM attendence 
WHERE
  id IN 
     (select min(id) from attendence where name = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, but if have more than one duplicated row, and you want to remove all duplicates but the last one (the one with the highest id) you can use this query:

```
DELETE FROM propertie p1
USING propertie p2
WHERE
  p1.name=p2.name
  AND p1.id<p2.id;
```

or this if you want to just remove duplicated SUPPORT_EMAILs:

```
DELETE FROM propertie p1
USING propertie p2
WHERE
  p1.name='SUPPORT_EMAIL'
  AND p1.name=p2.name
  AND p1.id<p2.id;
```

please see an example fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2acaa/1).